# match if a row in dataframe_2$column1 contains a string contained in column dataframe_1$column2, and return the string itself

Tags: r

I have a list of keywords in a dataframe column. Example:

**- dataframe_1$column_queries**

- query1
- query2
- query3
- query4

Then I have a dataframe with a column that contains the queries appearing in the previous column + some more words. Example:

**- dataframe_2$column_complex_queries**

- query1 other words
- query2 other words
- query3 other words
- query4 other words

I'm creating a new column that analyzes if the query is included and then return the query. I'm doing it manual one by one with the code:

```
dataframe_2 <- dataframe_2 %>% 
add_column(newcolumn = ifelse(grepl("query1", dataframe_2$column_complex_queries) == TRUE, "query1",
ifelse(grepl("query2", dataframe_2$column_complex_queries) == TRUE, "query2",
ifelse(grepl("query3", dataframe_2$column_complex_queries) == TRUE, "query3","query4")
```

This system works, but when you have a long list it is very time consuming. Is there any possible way to try to match if a row in `dataframe_2$column_complex_queries` contains a string contained in column `dataframe_1$column_queries`, and if it is true then return the string itself?

Many thanks

Update, example of code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(urltools)
library(anytime)
library(readxl)
library(RMySQL)
library(dplyr)
library(urltools)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
library(zoo) #for as.yearmon
library(lubridate)
library(formattable)
library(ggrepel)
library(plyr)
require(openxlsx)
library(expss)
library(fuzzyjoin)


brand <- c("Mango","Zara","Gucci", "Adidas")
string <- c("Mango","Zara","Gucci", "Adidas")
brands_df <- data.frame(brand, string)

keyword <- c("Mango throussers","throussers Gucci","t-shirt Gucci", "Zara shoes", "Adidas shoes")
search_volume <- c(100,20,300,400,500)
keywords_df <- data.frame(keyword, search_volume)


keywords_df <- keywords_df %>%
  add_column(category = ifelse (grepl("Mango", keywords_df$keyword) == TRUE, "Mango",
                                ifelse (grepl("Zara", keywords_df$keyword) == TRUE, "Zara",
                                        ifelse (grepl("Gucci", keywords_df$keyword) == TRUE, "Gucci","Adidas"))))
```

Comment: In your question you mention needing to compare `dataframe_1` and `dataframe_2`, but in your code your only reference is to `dataframe_2`. If you need to compare the two dataframes then you'll likely need to do a merge, but it would be helpful if you could post some of the data using `dput(head(dataframe_1))` and `dput(head(dataframe_2))`.

Comment: Are your keywords *literally* `query1`etc. or are these terms just placeholders for variable keywords?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_extract` from the package `stringr`. If the pattern exists in `column_complex_queries` then it will extract it.

```
library(tidyverse)

dataframe_2 %>% 
  mutate(newcolumn = str_extract(column_complex_queries, "query[1-4]"))
```

FYI, to add a column to your dataframe you should use `mutate` from the `dplyr` package. This way you do not have to reference the dataframe name, like `dataframe_2$column_complex_queries`.

---

**Update**

Based on your updated request:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

lookup <- with(brands_df, setNames(brand, string))


keywords_df %>% 
  mutate(newcolumn = lookup[str_extract(keyword, regex(paste(names(lookup), collapse = "|"), ignore_case = T))])
```

This works by extracting `string` if found in `keyword` and then using a named vector `lookup` to change the value to `brand`. I used `stringr::regex` with the argument `ignore_case = T` so that `"Mango"` would be matched in a string like, `"mango throssers"`.

Note: this will match the *first* found value. For example, `"Mango Gucci"` will have a value of `"Mango"` in `newcolumn`. The desired behavior if `keyword` contains more than one match is not clear and so I am assuming it's not a problem in your situation.

Or with `fuzzyjoin`:

```
fuzzyjoin::stringdist_left_join(keywords_df, 
                     rename(brands_df, keyword = string), 
                     by = c("keyword"), 
                     ignore_case = T,
                     method = "jaccard",
                     distance_col = "dist") %>% 
  select(-keyword.y) %>%
  rename(keyword = keyword.x) %>%
  group_by(keyword) %>% 
  slice_min(dist) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
```

**Output**

```
  keyword          search_volume brand 
  <chr>                    <dbl> <chr> 
1 Adidas shoes               500 Adidas
2 Mango throussers           100 Mango 
3 t-shirt Gucci              300 Gucci 
4 throussers Gucci            20 Gucci 
5 Zara shoes                 400 Zara
```

Comment: LMc as i can't compare them dataframe1 to dataframe 2, i use only dataframe1 and then use the list of keywords that appear in dataframe2, one by one using the ifelse statement.

Comment: Chris Ruehlemann actually this is just a made up data. I'll try to explain with a real example to make it easy. I have a list of keywords which relate to brand names, lets say for example channel, zara, prada,....then i export a list of keywords combinations that users type, as for example channel perfume, channel best clothes, channel shops near me, zara jackets, zara perfume,...Then I have the list of brands in the first column of the dataframe1 brands. I have the list of keywords combination in dataframe2 together with other data about each of the keywords.

Comment: (continue from previous comment) What I would like to do is check row 1 of dataframe2, we have there "channel perfume", then i want to go to the column brands of the dataframe1, see if there is any string matching. We know that in dataframe1 exist "channel", so this string match. and i want to return this string back.

Comment: @user399234 it would be best if you provided a small reproducible example. Also include in your question your expected output. This will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Hi LMc thanks for your reply and sorry for the delay in adding the code. I have added an example of code in the intro as allow more characters. Let me know if it is clear or if you need more info. :)

Comment: Thanks @LMc, when trying your code I get an error: for the first one ''Error in regex(paste(names(lookup), collapse = "|"), ignore_case = T) : 
  unused argument (ignore_case = T)''. The second option seems more difficult.

Comment: @user399234 `ignore_case` is an argument to the function `regex`. Make sure you have the library loaded and that your parentheses are correct. The second option is included to allow for fuzzy merging. You had that library loaded in your question.

Comment: Thanks @LMc, I was trying but nothing. I'll need to dedicate some time and I'll be back if I can make it work. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user399234 does this not work for the sample data you have posted?

Comment: Hi @LMc, not even when I try with the example I provide doesn't work

Comment: @user399234 the posted solution works on my computer with the data given. What "doesn't work" about it?

Comment: **Using the fuzzyjoin:**  1. First I delete the last %>%, as gives an error. 2. Then I get the error "Error in rename(brands_df, keyword = string) : unused argument (keyword = string)", so in order to avoid the rename issue I rename string to keyword at when creating the list and remove the line in the code related to rename 3. The I get the error "Error in stringdist_join(x, y, by, mode = "left", distance_col = distance_col,  : 
  argument "y" is missing, with no default" so I try to add brands_df, after keywords_df inside the fuzzyjoin function.

Comment: 4. Then I get the error "Error: All columns in a tibble must be vectors.
x Column `col` is NULL."

Comment: **Using the first options:** 1. I get the error "Error in regex(paste(names(lookup), collapse = "|"), ignore_case = T) : 
  unused argument (ignore_case = T)". 2. I remove ignore_case part of the code including the coma, and then I get the error: Error in UseMethod("type") : 
  no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "c('criterion', 'function')"